# Splitting words into letters in Java

Tags: java, split

**How can you split a word to its constituent letters?**

Example of code which is not working

```
 class Test {
         public static void main( String[] args) {
             String[] result = "Stack Me 123 Heppa1 oeu".split("\\a");                                                                                   

             // output should be
             // S
             // t
             // a
             // c
             // k
             // M
             // e
             // H
             // e
             // ...
             for ( int x=0; x<result.length; x++) {
                 System.out.println(result[x] + "\n");
             }
         }
     }
```

The problem seems to be in the character `\\a`.
It should be a [A-Za-z].

Comment: Your example doesn't make it clear if you want "123" to be split up or not.

Comment: patros: I do not want "123" to be split up.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to use `split("");`.

That will split it by every character.

However I think it would be better to iterate over a `String`'s characters like so:

```
for (int i = 0;i < str.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
}
```

It is unnecessary to create another copy of your `String` in a different form.

Comment: +1: Hmm, I didn't think about creating another copy of the string.  Good point.

Comment: One thing to consider here is str.charAt(i) will return a char. So if you need a String you will need to do Character.toString(str.charAt(i)). This will create a copy of that character, but that is still better than O(n) space that using str.split("") would give you.

Comment: this solution will give array of length 1 if input is empty string

Comment: The last comment is correct: An empty string is the **only** case where ```.split("")``` would add an extra (empty) element to the array.

Answer (score 30):

`"Stack Me 123 Heppa1 oeu".toCharArray()` ?

Comment: +1: Simple, concise, and can easily be fed to for.

Comment: Creating an extra char array is an extra step that is not necessary.

Comment: Depends. My _guess_ is that above a certain length an arrayCopy and direct array access is "faster" than calling hundreds of charAt's.

Comment: Calling `charAt` is O(1) because the String is implemented using an array in the back end.  Creating a copy will be slower always.

Comment: Calling `charAt(i)` is implemented to first make a sanity check on the input parameter then offsetting it with the internal offset, and after this yes, it is an array access.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
String [] strArr = Str.split("");
```

Comment: This adds an extra blank string to 0 position so array is one extra.

Answer (score 6):

Including numbers but not whitespace:

`"Stack Me 123 Heppa1 oeu".replaceAll("\\W","").toCharArray();`

`=> S, t, a, c, k, M, e, 1, 2, 3, H, e, p, p, a, 1, o, e, u`

Without numbers and whitespace:

`"Stack Me 123 Heppa1 oeu".replaceAll("[^a-z^A-Z]","").toCharArray()`

`=> S, t, a, c, k, M, e, H, e, p, p, a, o, e, u`

Answer (score 3):

```
 char[] result = "Stack Me 123 Heppa1 oeu".toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure he doesn't want the spaces to be output though.

```
for (char c: s.toCharArray()) {
    if (isAlpha(c)) {
       System.out.println(c);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] result = "Stack Me 123 Heppa1 oeu".split("**(?<=\\G.{1})**");
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: Your code thrown below error when executed.  `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
**(?<=\G.{1})**
^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2090)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
 at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2313)
 at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2355)`