# Split string into array of character strings

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to split a String into an array of single character Strings.

Eg, splitting "cat" would give the array "c", "a", "t"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521921/splitting-words-into-letters-in-java

Comment: As a quick reference, "".join(["c","a","t"]) to get "cat" back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting words into letters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521921/splitting-words-into-letters-in-java)

Comment: Java 8: `.split("")` will do it.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

```
"cat".split("(?!^)")
```

This will produce

> array ["c", "a", "t"]

Comment: How and why? Is this a regex meaning any character? Because in my mind, with the way split works, this should split on only the actual characters (, ?, !, ^, and ). However, it works as you say it does.

Comment: This is indeed a regex-expression, called a negative lookahead. Checkout the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Comment: @EW-CodeMonkey `(?!`...`)` is regex syntax for a negative assertion – it asserts that there is no match of what is inside it. And `^` matches the beginning of the string, so the regex matches at every position that is *not* the beginning of the string, and inserts a split there. This regex also matches at the end of the string and so would also append an empty string to the result, except that the `String.split` documentation [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) "trailing empty strings are not included in the resulting array".

Comment: In Java 8 the behavior of `String.split` was slightly changed so that *leading* empty strings produced by a zero-width match also are not included in the result array, so the `(?!^)` assertion that the position is not the beginning of the string becomes unnecessary, allowing the regex to be simplified to nothing – `"cat".split("")` – but in Java 7 and below that produces a leading empty string in the result array.

Comment: It creates an array of an entire string.

Answer (score 134):

```
"cat".toCharArray()
```

But if you need strings

```
"cat".split("")
```

Edit: which will return an empty first value.

Comment: "cat".split("") would return [, c, a, t], no? You will have a extra character in your Array...

Comment: The "cat".split("") does not work as expected by Matt, you will get an extra empty String => [, c, a, t].

Comment: This answer does now work if you're using Java 8. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22718904/1587046

Comment: This was a horrific change in jdk8 because i relied on split("") and did  workarounds cause of this silly empty first index. Now after upgrading to java8, it works as i would have expected it years ago. unfortunately now my workaround breaks my code... ggrrrr.

Comment: @Marc You should probably be using `.toCharArray()` anyway; it avoids regex and returns an array of `char` primitives so it's faster and lighter. It's odd to need an array of 1-character *strings*.

Comment: String[] newCAT = Arrays.copyOfRange(cat, 1, cat.length);

Comment: In android api 30 there isn't extra character and my code worked only on android api<30 please delete this answer lol!

Comment: `"cat".toCharArray()` is the correct solution

Answer (score 48):

```
String str = "cat";
char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Nitpicking, the original question asks for an array of String, not an array of Char.  However it's quite easy to get an array of String from here.

Comment: Yeah, I already know how to get an array of chars. I can just iterate through the char array and create a string from each one though, if there's no other way.

Comment: How would you convert `cArray` back to `String`?

Comment: ^12 years late but it's just `new String(cArray);`

Answer (score 12):

If characters beyond [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)) are expected on input (some CJK characters, new emoji...), approaches such as `"ab".split("(?!^)")` cannot be used, because they break such characters (results into `array ["a", "?", "?", "b"]`) and something safer has to be used:

```
"ab".codePoints()
    .mapToObj(cp -> new String(Character.toChars(cp)))
    .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
```

Answer (score 6):

`split("(?!^)")` does not work correctly if the string contains surrogate pairs. You should use `split("(?<=.)")`.

```
String[] splitted = "花ab".split("(?<=.)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted));
```

output:

```
[花, a, b, , , ]
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an edge case

Answer (score 5):

To sum up the other answers...

This works on all Java versions:

```
"cat".split("(?!^)")
```

This only works on Java 8 and up:

```
"cat".split("")
```

Answer (score 3):

An efficient way of turning a String into an array of one-character Strings would be to do this:

```
String[] res = new String[str.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    res[i] = Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
}
```

However, this does not take account of the fact that a `char` in a `String` could actually represent half of a Unicode code-point.  (If the code-point is not in the BMP.)  To deal with that you need to iterate through the code points ... which is more complicated.

This approach will be faster than using `String.split(/* clever regex*/)`, and it will probably be faster than using Java 8+ streams.  It is probable faster than this:

```
String[] res = new String[str.length()];
int 0 = 0;
for (char ch: str.toCharArray[]) {
    res[i++] = Character.toString(ch);
}
```

because `toCharArray` has to *copy* the characters to a new array.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is going to split a string into an array? You're just printing the string to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a for loop that goes through the String content and extract characters by characters using the `charAt` method.

Combined with an `ArrayList<String>` for example you can get your array of individual characters.

Comment: Maybe you could stand on one leg and sing "God Save the Queen".  Sorry, but this isn't even close to correct.

Answer (score 1):

If the original string contains [supplementary Unicode characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/supplementaryChars.html), then `split()` would not work, as it splits these characters into surrogate pairs. To correctly handle these special characters, a code like this works:

```
String[] chars = new String[stringToSplit.codePointCount(0, stringToSplit.length())];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < stringToSplit.length(); j++) {
    int cp = stringToSplit.codePointAt(i);
    char c[] = Character.toChars(cp);
    chars[j] = new String(c);
    i += Character.charCount(cp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my previous answer I mixed up with JavaScript. Here goes an analysis of performance in Java.

I agree with the need for attention on the Unicode Surrogate Pairs in Java String. This breaks the meaning of methods like `String.length()` or even the functional meaning of `Character` because it's ultimately a technical object which may not represent one character in human language.

I implemented 4 methods that split a string into list of character-representing strings (`String`s corresponding to human meaning of *character*s). And here's the result of comparison:

A line is a `String` consisting of 1000 arbitrary chosen emojis and 1000 ASCII characters (1000 times `<emoji><ascii>`, total 2000 "characters" in human meaning).

[image: Comparison of different splitting methods]

(discarding 256 and 512 measures)
[image]

Implementations:

- **codePoints** (java 11 and above)

```
    public static List<String> toCharacterStringListWithCodePoints(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return str.codePoints()
            .mapToObj(Character::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

- **classic**

```
    public static List<String> toCharacterStringListWithIfBlock(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
        int delta = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i += delta) {
            delta = 1;
            if (i < charArray.length - 1 && Character.isSurrogatePair(charArray[i], charArray[i + 1])) {
                delta = 2;
                strings.add(String.valueOf(new char[]{ charArray[i], charArray[i + 1] }));
            } else {
                strings.add(Character.toString(charArray[i]));
            }
        }
        return strings;
    }
```

- **regex**

```
    static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=.)");
    public static List<String> toCharacterStringListWithRegex(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return Arrays.asList(p.split(str));
    }
```

Annex (RAW DATA):

```
codePoints;classic;regex;lines
45;44;84;256
14;20;98;512
29;42;91;1024
52;56;99;2048
87;121;174;4096
175;221;375;8192
345;411;839;16384
667;826;1285;32768
1277;1536;2440;65536
2426;2938;4238;131072
```

Comment: [the java project in github](https://github.com/mtomim/string-splitter)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this simply by

```
const string = 'hello';
console.log([...string]); // -> ['h','e','l','l','o']
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax says

> Spread syntax (...) allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded...

So, strings can be *quite simply* spread into arrays of characters.

Comment: This is Javascript, the question is tagged java.

Comment: Yeah, I totally mixed up.

Comment: I posted another solution with performance analysis of different methods this time in Java.