# Making int array in parallel to java string array

Tags: java, arrays

The following code creates a string array 'one' as [c, a, t, a, n, d, d, o, g]. Now I want to create an int array 'two' in which place of every 'a' is  3 and all other places are filled by 5 forming

```
int two= {5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}
```

but the code is giving  every element equal to 5, so it prints as

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 :
```

The code I used starts here:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class StringInt {


public static void main(String[] args) {

      String str= "cat and dog";
      String[] word = str.split("\\s"); 
      String[] one = new String[0];
      for(int i=0; i<word.length; i++){
           one = ArrayUtils.addAll(one, word[i].split("(?!^)"));
      } 

        System.out.println("One : " + Arrays.toString(one));

        int[] b = new int[one.length];

        for(int j=0; j<one.length; j++){
            if(one[j]=="a"){
                b[j]=3;
             } else {
                b[j]=5;
             }
            System.out.print(b[j]+" ");

          }

        }
   }
```

Being new to programming and java I need help to rectify this code to get the required output:

```
5  3  5  3  5  5  5  5  5
```

Comment: With `split("(?!^)"` you seem to want to split your string to array of strings with single characters. If that is the case then you can avoid negative-look-ahead by [upgrading your JVM to Java8 and using `split("")`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22718744/1393766). You can also use `toCharArray()` to create array of characters `char[]` which would let you compare characters like you did in your code but you would need to use `'` instead of `"` since `"` means start/end of string and `'` represents start/end of character. So you could use code like `if(one[j]=='a'){`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `==` not `.equals()` to compare strings.

Use `one[j].equals("a")`.

Comment: After so many years...still `==equals` bringing lots of votes... :) Can't Stop MySelf +1.

Comment: Great TAsk, your answer has rectified my code and it is working according to my need.

Answer (score 2):

You use `==` when comparing primitives, like `int`, `double`, `char`, etc.

When comparing objects, one has to use the equals() method, which is a method that every object inherits from the Object class.

This is from the javadocs:

```
boolean equals(Object obj)
Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.
```

Since String is an object, and not a primitive, one must use the equals method to check for equality between two String objects.