# Split string of numbers into individual numbers

Tags: java, android, regex, string

How could I split the numbers in the string "542" into individual digits? On my desktop I can split the numbers using `String.split("")` and it works fine. But when run on Android, I get a `NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""`. 
This is my code:

```
public void render(int n, SpriteBatch batch) {
    String[] numbers = String.valueOf(n).split("");
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
        batch.draw(Assets.numbers[0][Integer.valueOf(numbers[i])], pos.x + (50 * i), pos.y);
}
```

Is there an alternative way?

Comment: You can just iterate over each digit as characters. Careful with negative values.

Comment: It is very unlikely that a NFE should be thrown on the context of `String.split(String regex)` - there just isn't a number to convert.

Comment: Well it did... On my Android device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.charAt`, that will give you a Character. Removing '0' will give you a value from 0 to 9.

```
public void render(int n, SpriteBatch batch) {
    String string = Integer.toString(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) 
        batch.draw(Assets.numbers[0][string.charAt(i) - '0'],
                   pos.x + (50 * i), pos.y);
}
```

Comment: Note that Integer.toString(n) and String.valueOf(n) should have the exact same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `String.split("")` will always leave the first index empty (that is, the String: ""). This is why you are getting `NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""` when trying to run `Integer.valueOf(numbers[0])`.

Suggest using `string.charAt(index)` to iterate over the characters in `String.valueOf(n)` instead.

Comment: "String.split("") will always leave the first index empty", not always, [at least not from Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-does-split-in-java-8-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-if-they-are-at-start-of).

Answer (score 1):

Splitting on `""` will cause the first element of the resulting array to be a blank, because the blank regex matches everywhere, including start of input.

You need to split *after* every character:

```
String[] digits = str.split("(?<=.)");
```

This regex is a *look behind* that assets there is a character before the match. Look behinds are non-consuming, so you don't lose any input making the split.