# How to take input in java without spaces?

Tags: java, arrays, input

How can i take input for an integer array in a single line without spaces. Number can be only from 0-9 so every thing is single digit.

Input:-

```
123456
```

Output:-

```
a[0]=1 a[1]=2 a[2]=3 a[3]=4 a[4]=5 a[5]=6
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: By _take input_ you mean from command line?

Comment: Are you just interested in reading single digits?  If not, how do you plan to distinguish `123456` being `1,2,3,4,5,6` vs `12,34,56`?

Comment: How would you know where one integer ends and the next one begins? This is only possible if you assume constant length for each int.

Comment: @Reimeus I have no idea on what function to use i am used to taking inputs with spaces in between!

Comment: @azurefrog yeah just single digits

Comment: @Audi : a simple nextInt() call on a Scanner can read a line of int separated by spaces, otherwise just use nextLine() and retrieve the digits by hand.

Comment: @Dici space is the delimiter for nextInt().

Comment: @bhargavg yea from command line only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take in in as a String and use split() -method like this:

`"123".split("(?!^)")`

will produce an array of strings

`array ["1", "2", "3"]`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are getting input as String you could do something like (streams and lambdas are available since Java 8)

```
String input = "123456";
int[] array = input.chars().map(i->i-'0').toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

This code can be considered as shorter version of

```
String input = "123456";
int[] array = new int[input.length()];
int i = 0;
for (char c : input.toCharArray())
    array[i++] = c - '0';
```

Anyway this solution is based on idea that integer value or `char` represents its index in Unicode table. Since digits are ordered as `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` we are interested in differences between position of checked character and position of `'0'`. For example `'3'` is placed at index [`51`](http://unicode-table.com/en/0033/) while index of `'0'` is [48](http://unicode-table.com/en/0030/) so `int value = '3'-'0'` is translated as `int value = 51 - 48` which creates integer with value `3`.

---

Or if that is an option you could get `char[]` array instead of `int[]` which will contain all characters from string by simply using `toCharArray`

```
String input = "123456";
char[] array = input.toCharArray();
```

---

If you are also interested in result as `String[]` then [since Java 8 you can simply use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-does-split-in-java-8-sometimes-remove-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array)

```
String input = "123456";
String[] array = input.split("");
```

instead of cryptic (even for those with basic regex knowledge): `split("(?!^)")`, `split("(?<!^)")`, `split("(?<=\\d)")` or whatever regex you can think of.

Comment: Yours also works but i need a simpler solution so i prefer the previous one no offense. :) thanks:)

Comment: @Audi What do you mean by simpler? IMHO `toCharArray` is most descriptive and simplest solutions. Also if you are interested in `String[]` result then as stated in my answer you can simply use `split("")` (this feature was added precisely to avoid regexes like `split("(?!^)")`).

Answer (score 0):

If you assume your integers are all single-digit, you can do the following, but I don't see the interest of doing so :

```
 Scanner sc     = new Scanner(System.in);
 String  s      = sc.nextLine();
 int[]   values = new int[s.length()]; 
 for (int i=0 ; i<values.length ; i++) 
     values[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to realize that while the `Scanner` class parses things using a separator by default, there is a method called [`findInLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine(java.util.regex.Pattern)) which "Attempts to find the next occurrence of the specified pattern ignoring delimiters."

You can create a `Pattern` which matches a single digit, and then ask the `Scanner` to parse through sans-separator like so:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("123456");
Pattern digit = Pattern.compile("\\d");
String nextInt = scan.findInLine(digit);
while (nextInt != null) {
    System.out.println(nextInt);
    nextInt = scan.findInLine(digit);
}


output:
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

> "123456".toCharArray()