# splitting string in infix form

Tags: java, string, text, split

There is something that I want to know. I have homework where they want us to take two string input in polynomial form, and there is lots of implementation. Here my question: when I take the input from the user, I can split the string into polynomial parts but it goes wrong:

The string:  `"-x^3 - 6x^2 + 4x + 22"`

I want to split this like:

```
-x^3                      
- 6x^2 
+ 4x 
+ 22
```

but it prints

```
package splitmethod;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class uygulama {

  public static void main(String args[]){


      System.out.println("lütfen parçalmak istidigniz polinomu girniz ");

      Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

      String polinom= input.nextLine();

      String[] result;

      System.out.println("");

      result=polinom.replaceAll("\\s+","").split("(?<=[+-])");

      for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){

          System.out.println(result[i]);
```

Comment: Please take more time and rewrite your question.

Comment: Aleady the 5th version of the question, but no one fixed the title ...

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and you haven't said what the actual output is. You should probably fix these things.

Comment: no, my code works  and i wrote what i want to print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=[+-])` means to split on place which has `+` or `-` *before it*. So for data like `-x^3-6x^2+4x+22` you are splitting here (I will mark this place with `|`)

```
-|x^3-|6x^2+|4x+|22
```

What you want is to split on place which has `+` or `-` *after it* (and don't split on `-` or `+` placed at start of entire string). So instead of look-behind `(?<=...)` you need to use look-ahead `(?=...)`.

Example: `|-x^3|-6x^2|+4x|+22` where `|` represents place to split. As you see I also placed `|` at start of string because it has `+` or `-` after it.

So try to use `split("(?=[+-])")`

If you are using Java 8 you will get correct results because for [zero-length](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) (or zero-width) regex matches (like the one from look-around mechanism), [empty strings at start of result arrays are removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-does-split-in-java-8-sometimes-remove-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array) so you will not end up with `["", "-x^3", "-6x^2", "+4x", "+22"]` array but
`["-x^3", "-6x^2", "+4x", "+22"]`.

If you are using earlier version of Java you will need to add condition to prevent matching this first `|` before `-x^3` element. You can do it by adding `(?<!^)` to your regex to make sure that place of match (in your case place of split) is not right after start of string (represented by `^`):

So in pre Java 8  versions use `split("(?=[+-])(?<!^)")`

---

Other way to avoid empty string which could be returned because of splitting on `-` at start of String is to use another instance of Scanner class with delimiter `(?=[+-])` which will "parse" input from user, so your code could look like

```
String polinom = "-x^3 - 6x^2 + 4x + 22";//here you pass data from user

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(polinom);
scanner.useDelimiter("(?=[+-])");

while (scanner.hasNext())
    System.out.println(scanner.next());

scanner.close();
```

Output:

```
-x^3 
- 6x^2 
+ 4x 
+ 22
```

Comment: thank you so much , i have been searching hours to find this solution :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually think you need to use `regex`. Just iterate through the `String` would be enough and check for `+/-` would be enough. Something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<polinom.length;i++) {
    if(i!=0 && (polinom.charAt(i)=='-' || polinom.charAt(i)=='+')) {
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(polinom.charAt(i));
    } else {
        sb.append(polinom.charAt(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

So basically you buffer `polinom` and whenever you meet `+` or `-` you know that one term in the polynomial has ended. So you print the buffer and start a new buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The regexp `"(?<=[+-])"` is "positive lookbehind". This means that it will split **after** the `+` or `-`. You need "positive lookahead", `"(?=[+-])"`.

But anyway, as you're removing the spaces before doing this, you'll get your `+` and `-` without any space between them and the operands,

```
-x^3
+6x^2
+4x
+22
```

which is not what you said you wanted. Personally, for the sake of parsing infix operations I would go with splitting by the white spaces, so that the operators are separate from the actual terms.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class uygulama {
    public static void main(String args[]) {


      System.out.println("lütfen parçalmak istidigniz polinomu girniz ");

      Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

      String polinom= input.nextLine();

      String[] result;

      System.out.println("");

      result = polinom.split(" "); //just splits the words by space so the signs in front are not stored in the same array as the addressed variable/coefficient combo

      for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){

          System.out.println(result[i]);
      }

    }

}
```