# String split() method not giving right result

Tags: java, string

I have a string like "2020". When I split it with split(""). Then i checked its length. It is giving me 5 . But it should give 4. What is the reason

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-does-split-in-java-8-sometimes-remove-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array) may explain

Comment: When I run split on the same string, I get the length you expect, 4. See https://ideone.com/QKf5Bb

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What are you trying to achieve, anyway?

Comment: The behaviour has changed in Java 8. You would get expected result there.

Comment: @Reimeus Now I understand

Comment: @JonSkeet It was annoying behaviour of Java before version 8 where it was improved. Often we had to split on `(?!^)` to avoid splitting on empty space which was placed at start of the String.

Comment: Interesting. I still wonder what the OP is trying to achieve that couldn't be more readably achieved in a different way.

Comment: @dasamit7 What are you trying to achieve with this code? If you want to know how many characters there is in string you can simply call `yourString.length()` method. If you want to iterate over all characters you can simply use `char[] chars = yourStirng.toCharArray()` and iterate over it, or use `yourStirng.charAt(index)`. Why do you want to create `String[]` array?

Comment: @Pshemo. I know that but I wanted to know why that was happening with split method.

Comment: Then you probably found your answer in duplicates. If not consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/q/28486166/1393766.

Comment: @Pshemo I understand that now