# Regex: in what cases the result of `/(?!^)/` would be different from `//`?

Tags: java, regex

Apparently the `split` function in Java has changed from Java 7 to Java 8. 
( More here: 
[Why in Java 8 split sometimes removes empty strings at start of result array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array) )

Some people are suggesting to use `split("?!^")` instead of `split("")` (In Java 7).

My main question is how to interpret `/(?!^)/`? Is there any case where it is different from `//`?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the suggested regex is `split("(?!^)")` (as opposed to the invalid regex you posted). `(?!^)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that matches anywhere except at `^` (the beggining of the string).

As you already mentioned, the behaviour of `split()` changed in [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), and a zero-width match at the beginning however never produces such empty leading substring.

Therefore, if you use `split("(?!^)")` you will get the same behaviour independent of the Java version.