# unable to correctly validate balanced parenthesis parsing in java method

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a method that's supposed to validate accurate opening and closing parenthesis in a string using java. This method will be used to parse mathematical expressions so it's important for the parenthesis to be balanced. For some reason, it is returning false in both of these runs:

```
System.out.println(parChecker("(()"));  // returns false :-)
System.out.println(parChecker("((()))")); // returns false :-(  WHY??
```

Here is the method that uses a stack to solve the problem. Something is wrong here becuase it's returning false for a balanced set of parenthesis as well. What's the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
public static boolean parChecker(String str) {
    String[] tokens = str.split("");
    int size = tokens.length;
    Stack theStack = new Stack(size);
    int index = 0;
    boolean balanced = true;
    while ((index < size) && balanced) {
        String symbol = tokens[index];
        if (symbol.equals("(")) {
            theStack.push(symbol);
        } else {
            if (theStack.isEmpty()) {
                balanced = false;
            } else {
                theStack.pop();
            }
        }
        index++;
    }

    if (balanced && theStack.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here is my stack class that I'm using:

```
public class Stack {

    private Object [] stack;
    private int maxSize = 0;
    private int top;

    public Stack(int size){
        maxSize = size;
        stack = new Object[maxSize];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void push(Object obj){
        top++;
        stack[top] = obj;
    }

    public Object pop(){
        return stack[top--];
    }

    public Object peek(){
        return stack[top];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (top == -1);
    }

    public boolean isFull(){
        return (top == maxSize -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't use just debug it?

Comment: If you really want to parse arithmetic expressions, create a grammar. Based on the grammar, create a parser, which will give you an abstract syntax tree. You might want to read up on some basic compiler techniques. If you keep doing it like this, your code will get messy, I guarantee it.

Comment: my goal was to learn the use of a stack data-structure. This is one use of it. I don't care about a parser otherwise. Lets get back to the issue. Any ideas why it's returning a false?

Comment: Just find the line in the loop where you set balanced to true

Comment: What Stack class and Java version are you using? There is no `Stack(int)` constructor in Java 5, 6 and 7.

Comment: It's my own stack class. Basic implementation of a stack

Comment: Then that's where your problem is. Can you post it?

Comment: @Kenny - I've added the stack class as well.

Comment: It looks okay.. firing up Eclipse ;-) Ok, the 2nd line returns true for me.
**UPDATE** See [code here](https://ideone.com/8y9Fri)

Comment: HUH??? Why not me>>?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem either. For the given input-String (`"((()))"`), I get the result `true`. Did you recompile your code after the last change you made?

Comment: It works in Java 8, doesn't work in Java 7.

Comment: @RealSkeptic [This link](https://ideone.com/aeBdGb) is the same but with Java 7, also works..

Comment: @Kenny Don't trust Ideone on such matters... See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22718744/4125191) and test it on real Java 7 and 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate problem is this

```
String[] tokens = str.split("");
```

Gives you first char = "" if you use `java 1.7` or less, so you will exit your loop since stack is empty...

Note: this has been changed in `java 1.8` [split difference between java 1.7 and 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array)

change to:

```
char[] tokens = str.toCharArray();
```

I guess however that you need to consider the fact that there can be chars before your first `(` and that you may have other chars then `(` and `)`

Comment: Huh? No that's not the issue. Split string is going to return an array of tokens in String.

Comment: Also you cannot assign a `char[]` to a `String[]`.

Comment: @Doublespeed Please use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens))`) to see the result of the split. Peter Friberg is right about that.

Comment: Yea. this answer is irrelevant and inaccurate.

Comment: Why do you need to split into tokens? Just iterate through each character in the string and increment the counter for '(' and decrement for ')'. Whenever the countre goes negative there is a mismatch. and if the counter is non-zero at the end you also have a problem.

What do you want to do with escaped parentheses, or parentheses inside a comment or inside quotes?

Comment: ... You just officially lost the possibility of gaining help on this site.  We're here to help you.  The fact is, the first string will be an empty string.

Comment: Still this is NOT the problem.

Comment: trust me  @Doublespeed with this change his example will give true as long as first char is (

Comment: @Doublespeed The answer is accurate. Including its last line which means that your `else` condition is wrong as you are assuming that everything that is not a `(` is automatically a `)` which is not going to happen in a real expression.

Comment: Doesn't matter, I'm referring to just this example: (()))())()()(((())))))(

Comment: First char is empty, try with System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens)) you get 7 chars with first empty,,,, you exit loop since stack is empty

Comment: OHH Sh*&.. Okay. Java issue. Python doesn't screw you like this. So I should split using chars? Thank you!

Comment: If you have the possibilty use an compiler like eclipse, that way its easy to debug your code.. it will save you alot of time... Have fun

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, there is no problem with the code (*turns out it's a Java 7 specific issue..*).

I would like to offer a replacement method though, for educational purposes, that is shorter, and and is tolerant of other characters being present:

```
public static boolean parChecker(String str) {
    Stack stack = new Stack(str.length());
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
        switch (c) {
        case '(':
            stack.push(c);
            break;
        case ')':
            if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != Character.valueOf('('))
                return false;
        }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

As requested, here's another solution that doesn't use a stack:

```
public static boolean parChecker(String str) {
    str = str.replaceAll("[^()]", "");
    while (str.contains("()"))
        str = str.replace("()", "");
    return str.isEmpty();
}
```

And one more for the road: @FredK's algorithm:

```
public static boolean parChecker(String str) {
    int depth = 0;
    for ( char c : str.toCharArray() )      
        if ( ( depth += c == '(' ? 1 : c == ')' ? -1 : 0 ) < 0 )
            return false;
    return depth == 0;
}
```

Comment: Vote for Kenney.. mine was mostly a debug answer, even if some problems where present ; )

Comment: Thank you! I upvoted this. But @Petter you pointed me to exactly what was wrong with my code and shed light onto the screwness of string.split. So I had to accept your answer. But this answer is a great way to handle the code.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thanks! You deserve your votes too, for your efforts! Although, I haven't been able to reproduce getting an empty string: `for ( String s : "()".split("") )
   System.out.println(s);`

Comment: Kenny it turns out you are using java 8. In which they have fixed the issue. I'm on 7 and am seeing an empty string leading and ending the split

Comment: @Kenny Because you are not seeing it!... the first is empty!, use your try System.out.println(" " + s)

Comment: @PetterFriberg  Ahh, allright. I didn't want to go through the trouble of installing Java 7 so I used the ideone with Java 7, but apparently they run it on Java 8 and just compile with `-source 1.7`.. And I tried with `...println("FOO: " + s )` but it still only prints 2 lines... So you're right, it's fixed in Java 8 (or, 1.8 really ;-)) If you mention this is a Java 7 issue I'll give your answer an upvote.

Comment: I also learned something new.... had no clue that split was changed in java 1.8 (need to edit my answer)

Comment: If you want to be educational, perhaps you should add a solution without a stack, because one is really not necessary.

Comment: @RealSkeptic its OP class, not the java Stack

Comment: @PetterFriberg Me neither. But to be honest, I haven't done much Java since Java 6 ;-) Anyway you got the upvote, because now you addressed the real issue. Btw, I've seen this weird split behaviour in Perl and PHP too.

Comment: Yes, I know, but you said you are offering this solution to be educational. Remember that StackOverflow is not just for the OP. Of course, since your answer is accurate and solves the issues in the OP, you don't have to. I'm just suggesting it since you talked about educating.

Comment: @RealSkeptic there you go.

Comment: @Kenney, hmmm you need (), same strange code as OP (correctly validate balanced parenthesis) i guess you use it with numbers normally... es (1+3)*8

Comment: I know that he is only asking about example which only includes () but I guess that someone arriving on this question whats to check expressions like (1+3)*(1+(8) to see if correctly validate balanced parenthesis your str.replace("()", "" ) will not work. Your fault that you like to educational : )