# Processing - when parsing string to float NullPointerException is thrown

Tags: java, parsing, nullpointerexception, floating-point, processing

I have a string `-0.06,0.00,-0.99`. I want to parse the first number to a float.

I am using:

```
String myString = "-0.06,0.00,-0.99";
float myFloat = float(split(myString, ",")[0]);
println(split(myString, ",")[0]); // prints -0.06
```

The second line throws a `NullPointerException`.

I have also tried the following and got the exact same error.

```
 float myFloat = Float.parseFloat(split(myString, ",")[0]);
```

How do I parse a string to a float without getting a `NullPointerException`.

Actual MVCE:

I am using processing to take input from my serial line by line. The first input is `"-0.06,0.00,-0.99"`.

```
buffer = port.readStringUntil('\n'); //take input from serial til line-break

float[] acceleration;
if (buffer != null) {
  if (buffer.indexOf(",") != -1) {
    buffer = trim(buffer);
    acceleration[0] = float(buffer.split(",")[0]); // this throws the error
  }
}
```

Comment: Both lines print -0.06 for me. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that contains exactly the code you're running.

Comment: It's probably this: `accelleration[0]` throws the NPE because `accelleration` isn't initialized.

Comment: And that solved it! Thanks so much. Such a stupid folly on my part.

Answer (score 0):

`Java` contains wrapper classes around the `primitive` types. For example, there is a `Float` class that wraps the `float` primitive. These wrapper classes have `valueOf(String s)` functions, which can parse a `String` representation of those `primitive` types into their actual `primitive` forms. Calling `Float.valueOf(stringRepresentationOfAFloat)` will give you a `float` variable if it is in the correct format.

See my code below for an example:

```
    String floatCsv = "-0.06,0.00,-0.99";
    String [] floatCsvSplit = floatCsv.split(",");
    for(String floatStringValue : floatCsvSplit){
        float floatVariable = Float.valueOf(floatStringValue);
        System.out.println(floatVariable);
    }
```

Comment: This is Processing, not just Java. See the reference for the `float()` function: https://www.processing.org/reference/floatconvert_.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String myString = "-0.06,0.00,-0.99";
float myFloat = Float.parseFloat(myString.split(",")[0]);
System.out.println(myFloat); // prints -0.06
```

Comment: This is Processing, not Java. See the reference for the `split()` function: https://www.processing.org/reference/split_.html

Comment: I think it should be fine to use either Processing's wrapped functions or Java's original String methods, as long as point get's across.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I don't disagree. But OP's problem had nothing to do with the `parse()` or `Float.parseFloat()` functions, so this answer doesn't really help much.

Comment: true, the error is a null pointer exception, so uninitialised data as Kenney pointed out 4 days ago

Answer (score -1):

Are you perhaps running Java 1.7? There is a bug in that version, resolved in 1.8, where `String.split()` returns one empty element at the beginning of the array.

Try printing `split(myString, ",")`; you should see something like `["", "-0.06", "0.00", "-0.99"]`.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554277/unable-to-correctly-validate-balanced-parenthesis-parsing-in-java-method/) for more information.

Comment: Ok, was worth a shot ;-) So, if you print `split(myString, ",")` you do see `["-0.06", "0.00", "-0.99"]`?

Comment: Hmm... I ran this `println(split(myString, ",")); ` which output `-0.06 0.00 -0.97`. Oddly using `System.out.println(split(myString, ","))` gave me `[Ljava.lang.String;@1c9570e4`.

Comment: You'll want to use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) for that second println.

Comment: This is Processing, not Java. The `println()` function handles arrays just fine.

Comment: @KevinWorkman `System.out.println` is Java, AFAIK - as well as `[Ljava.lang.String;@1c9570e4`

Comment: @Kenney Yes, it is. But Processing also has a `println()` function: https://processing.org/reference/println_.html

Comment: @KevinWorkman **Note** That using Processing's ```println()``` will print the array only if the array is alone in the statement(e.g. isn't concatenated with a string), otherwise the the object's address in memory is listed: ```String[] s = {"0.1","-0.5","0.3"};
println(s);
println("values: " + s);
println("values:");
printArray(s);```