# How to do form block letter printing?

Tags: formatting, jasper-reports

I want to print in block letters in a jasper print. E.g. I have a Bank Format and I want the name to come in the boxes. How does one do that?

```
Name: [F][I][R][S][T][ ][N][A][M][E]
```

- Option1 - Print cell by cell with a `${FIRST_NAME}.charAt(x)` - which is unsustainable
- Option2 - Add spaces between characters but this changes based on font size
- Option3 - Add padding spaces to the end of the text. Stretch the text to the full width available and characters get distributed equally - how does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal achieved using a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

If you like to achieve it with other fonts or the spacing is very large you can use a subreport (that is called every time you need the fixed space)

### Example

**Main report** (I'm using parameter to test)

Call the subreport with a datasource that contains each letter, I'm using `$P{testText}.split("")` , since `char[]` is not allowed in the `JRBeanArrayDataSource`.

Note: [split will give empty first String in java7 but not in java8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33554404/5292302)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MainFixedSpace" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d2bcb5ab-c751-4f39-8753-561b8a6ac629">
    <parameter name="testText" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Hello world"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\jdd\\projects\\StackTrace\\jasper\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="25" uuid="76f53ca9-da1f-46c8-bb3b-aca0dc43d2d3"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanArrayDataSource($P{testText}.split(""))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "MainFixedSpace_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Subreport**

Setup the the fixed space column count in my case 20 columns on each row (you need to adapted it to your case) and set `printOrder="Horizontal"` The `_THIS` field will let you access the letter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MainFixedSpace_subreport" columnCount="20" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="27" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="77ba37de-32e1-4ec6-8496-58d716d0340d">
    <field name="_THIS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="27" height="25" uuid="ffb27000-41ba-419f-8836-b24dbb0dbb25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: Result]