# java programming on a Mac split

Tags: java, split

I am trying to built an app inside my Mac using Eclipse

```
String h="asd";

    String o[]=h.split("");
    System.out.println(o.length);
```

the result is: 4 .which is wrong 
but in windows its gives :3 .which is correct

both Mac and windows is up to date

Comment: Shouldn't have any problems really going between a Mac and a Windows box. Only thing I can think of would be that it's some weird character encoding issue, or an extra space.

Comment: Are you using the same Java version ? There is a difference in Java 8, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array