# how to convert date to int array?

Tags: java, arrays, split, calendar

I want make to make `hours` and `minutes` arrays which for `19:49` should contain

```
hours[0] = 1
hours[1] = 9
minutes[0] = 4
minutes[1] = 9
```

Problem is that when I execute code:

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
String hour[] = String.valueOf(rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)).split("");
String minute[] = String.valueOf(rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE)).split("");
```

and when I print this

```
System.out.println(hour[0] + ""+hour[1] + ":" + minute[0] +""+minute[1]);
```

I have this output `1:4`, but it should be `19:49`

Update: I am using 1.7 JDK and form what I see `hour[2]` contains `9` and `minute[2]` `9`.

Comment: Works fine for me. Voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: Also, that's a `String` array.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I guess you're using Java8? Java8 ignore the empty string in front of the very first match. Java7 doesn't, that's why some numbers aren't there (index 0 is the empty string and index 1 is the first number). But since I'm on thr phone I cant write a proper answer.

Comment: im use 1.7 JDK but hour[2] return me 9 and minute[2] return me 9;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess what you are looking for is something like this

```
    int[] hour = new int[2];
    int[] minute = new int[2];

    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

    int tempHour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int tempMin  = rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    hour[0]   = (int)Math.floor(tempHour/10);
    hour[1]   = tempHour%10;

    minute[0] = (int)Math.floor(tempMin/10);
    minute[1] = tempMin%10;

    System.out.println(hour[0] + "" + hour[1] + ":" + minute[0] + "" + minute[1]);
```

Comment: no i want to have array int hour[] and array int minute[]
and when we have 10:31 in arrays i should have 
hour[0] = 1 
hour[1] = 0
minute[0] = 3
minute[1] = 1

Comment: edited. Check this out. If any explanations needed feel free to ask)

Answer (score 2):

Problem in pre-Java-8 is that when we `split(delimiter)` string like

```
delimiter[Data]delimiter[Data]delimiter[Data]
```

we will get as result array

```
"", "[Data]", "[Data]", "[Data]"
```

In your case delimiter is empty string `""`, and empty string exists not only inbetween characters, but also at start and end of string.

To solve this problem you could use `split("(?!^)")` which will split on each place as long it doesn't have start of string (`^`) after it (which excludes empty string at start of your text).

In Java 8 this behaviour changed: [Why in Java 8 split sometimes removes empty strings at start of result array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array)