# unexpected behaviour of "grouped" in scala

Tags: list, scala, grouping

I am learning scala right now. When I wrote a statement as below,

`"abcdpqrs".split("").grouped(2).map(_.mkString("")).mkString("|")`

i expected it to print,

`ab|cd|pq|rs`

but instead it is printing,

`a|bc|dp|qr|s`

I find this behaviour erratic. Am I missing something or is there anything else which can partition the list as I expected?

Comment: Running your code, I see "ab|cd|pq|rs".  Are you sure you copied it correctly to the description?

Comment: I was trying it while solving problems in hackerrank and thats what it gave me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting `a|bc|dp|qr|s` as a result because of `split("")`

```
scala> "abcdpqrs".split("")
res0: Array[String] = Array("", a, b, c, d, p, q, r, s)
```

If you do this without `split("")` you get

```
scala> "abcdpqrs".grouped(2).map(_.mkString("")).mkString("|")
res4: String = ab|cd|pq|rs
```

which I think is what you want

**EDIT**

For the record @marstran has helpfully pointed out that this only happens in java 7 - the behaviour of split was changed with java 8 and instead `split("")` will give

```
scala> "abcdpqrs".split("")
res0: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d, p, q, r, s)
```

Comment: no problem! I only know this because it's caught me out before!

Comment: thanks anyway! I was breaking my head on this for past 30 mins! i'll accept your answer soon!

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior at all.  In my local scala shell (2.11.7 on Linux), running `"abcdpqrs".split("").grouped(2).map(_.mkString).mkString("|")` results in `res6: String = ab|cd|pq|rs`.  Is there possibly something different in my shell than in yours?

Comment: I didn't try on my local machine, I was using hackerrank's shell. But the thing which is said above, solved my problem

Comment: @bedwyr that's really weird - I hope not, I'm just using the standard repl here?

Comment: Wow, very interesting :)  Also, when I use `split` on that string, I don't see the initial empty-string in the Array: `res3: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d, p, q, r, s)`.  Will keep an eye out for this in the future.

Comment: The behaviour of the `split` method actually changed slightly in Java 8. When called with the empty string as a parameter, Java 7 will give return `Array("", a, b, c, d, p, q, r, s)`, while Java 8 will return `Array(a, b, c, d, p, q, r, s)`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array/27477312#27477312

Comment: @marstran good knowledge!! Yes, I'm using java 7 on my work machine, so that solves that mystery!