# Java String Split: Curly brackets issues

Tags: java, syntax

I'm writing a code to check for balanced brackets but I'm having a problem, probably with Java syntax. In the following code:

```
String s0 = "{{[[(()[])]{()}]}}}";
String[] s1 = s0.split("");
if (s1[0] == "{")
    System.out.println("Ok");
else
    System.out.println("Nope");
```

Why the comparison

```
s1[0] == "{"
```

is not true?

Comment: Does this `s0.split("");` even work?

Comment: @ScaryWombat that may depend on Java version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array

Comment: Why split on empty string? You could use `toCharArray` if you want an array of character, which you **can** use `==` on

Comment: @cricket_007 - Don't you know?  Once you have learned about regexes, you never need to use any other tools.  Ever.  :-)

Comment: seems like split creates strings by new String("}"),so == returns false because its a new object.but you can compere it with equals() method