# How to change one array's values from another array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String [] board = new String [9];
String [] sequence = new String [8];

sequence[0] = board[0]+board[1]+board[2];
sequence[1] = board[0]+board[3]+board[6];
sequence[2] = board[0]+board[4]+board[8];
sequence[3] = board[1]+board[4]+board[7];
sequence[4] = board[2]+board[5]+board[8];
sequence[5] = board[2]+board[4]+board[6];
sequence[6] = board[3]+board[4]+board[5];
sequence[7] = board[6]+board[7]+board[8];
```

Say I was to make `sequence[0]="XXO";`

How could I take `sequence[0]` and change the the board points so that:

```
board[0]="X";
board[1]="X";
board[2]="O";
```

I am trying to run this for loop and I have to initialize the board array  before the sequences part as I am printing it out to the screen and can't have the values be null.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++
{
    if(sequence[i].equals("X"+"X"+" "))
    {
        sequence[i] = "XXO";
    }
}
```

Comment: now it is more complicated, what did you mean by `choice+choice` i really don't get you

Comment: I am making a TicTacToe game where the person can choose what they want to be and the computer chooses the opposite of that, but I edited to make more sense to you now.  I also do not want to hard code all of the ways that one could win so I thought this would be much easier, but I need to make it so that the sequence changes the board slots.

Comment: why you don't use List instead maybe you need something like this `List<String> board = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] sequence = new String[8];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (sequence[i].equals("X" + "X" + " ")) {
                sequence[i] = "XXO";
                board.addAll(Arrays.asList(sequence));
            }
        }` ?

Comment: I need to make it so the Board[2] becomes an O.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**String::split**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) which return an array of String for example :

```
String[] board;//you could also to not initialize the array here 
               //because you will do that in split
String[] sequence = new String[8];
sequence[0] = "XXO";
board = sequence[0].split("");//split and initialize the board array

//print the values
System.out.println(board[0]);
System.out.println(board[1]);
System.out.println(board[2]);
```

Output

```
X
X
O
```

Comment: note that java 7(to which you have linked to) and below, would result in an empty String at the beginning, when using `string.split("")`. For this reason, you should probably link to the Java 8 Docs. For Java 8, and above, your way is perfect. Take an upvote

Comment: thank you @ChandlerBing i appreciate it, but i really don't get you what is the difference between split in java 7 and java 8 sorry what did you mean by **would result in an empty String at the beginning, when using string.split(""). For this reason, you should probably link to the Java 8 Docs. For Java 8, and above** ?

Comment: I was referring to this. [Why in Java 8 split sometimes removes empty strings at start of result array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array/)

Comment: waahhh this is really a new information for me, thank you @ChandlerBing you already teach me something new, so i should to change the link to java 8 right?

Comment: Haha, I feel honored!

Comment: Sorry, but would this work for the other sequences such as sequence[7]?

Comment: what did you mean @NathanMatteson ?

Comment: I'm running a for loop that runs through all the sequences and checks them to see if there is an xx" " and if there is put an x in the final space and there are 8 other sequences, so I was wondering if this could apply to all of the other board slots.

Comment: ok can you share your code please so we can help you @NathanMatteson

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't store the same data in different ways ([the Don't Repeat Yourself principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), sometimes because it leads to a mess like this.

One correct way to do what you want is the following:

```java
board[0] = String.valueOf(sequence[0].charAt(0));
board[1] = String.valueOf(sequence[0].charAt(1));
board[2] = String.valueOf(sequence[0].charAt(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want only one character as an element in your board array you can use character array instead of String array and then can use

```
char board[] = new char[9];
board = sequence[0].toCharArray();
```