# Difference between Kotlin and Java String split with Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, kotlin

If we have a `val txt: kotlin.String = "1;2;3;"` and like to split it into an array of numbers, we can try the following:

```
val numbers = string.split(";".toRegex())
//gives: [1, 2, 3, ]
```

The trailing empty `String` is included in the result of [`CharSequence.split`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html).

On the other hand, if we look at Java `String`s, the result is different:

```
val numbers2 = (string as java.lang.String).split(";")
//gives: [1, 2, 3]
```

This time, using [`java.lang.String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), the result does not include the trailing empty `String`. This behaviour actually is intended given the corresponding JavaDoc:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a *limit argument of zero*. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

In Kotlin's version though, `0` also is the default `limit` argument as documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html), yet internally Kotlin maps that `0` on a negative value `-1` when `java.util.regex.Pattern::split` is [called](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.20/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/regex/Regex.kt#L192):

```
nativePattern.split(input, if (limit == 0) -1 else limit).asList()
```

It seems to be working as intended but I'm wondering why the language seems to be restricting the Java API since a limit of `0` is not provided anymore.

Comment: I don't know the reason they chose to make it that way but at least to me it feels more intuitive. If using regex you can use a negative lookahead instead: `;(?!$)` or `;(?!;*$)`

Comment: I've always considered Java's `limit` semantics a chaos. It's haphazard, self-inconsistent and virtually impossible to memorize.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The implementation implies that it's the behavior of `java.lang.String.split` achieved by passing `limit = 0` that is lost in Kotlin. Actually, from my point of view, it was removed to achieve consistency between the possible options in Kotlin.

Consider a string `a:b:c:d:` and a pattern `:`.

Take a look at what we can have in Java:

`limit < 0` → `[a, b, c, d, ]` 
`limit = 0` → `[a, b, c, d]` 
`limit = 1` → `[a:b:c:d:]`  
`limit = 2` → `[a, b:c:d:]`  
`limit = 3` → `[a, b, c:d:]`  
`limit = 4` → `[a, b, c, d:]`  
`limit = 5` → `[a, b, c, d, ]` (goes on the same as with `limit < 0`) 
 
`limit = 6` → `[a, b, c, d, ]`  
...

It appears that the `limit = 0` option is somewhat unique: it has the trailing `:` neither replaced by an additional entry, as with `limit < 0` or `limit >= 5`, nor retained in the last resulting item (as with `limit` in 1..4).

It seems to me that the Kotlin API improves the consistency here: there's no special case that, in some sense, loses the information about the last delimiter followed by an empty string – it's left in place either as the delimiter in the last resulting item or as a trailing empty entry.

IMO, the Kotlin function seems to better fit the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). The zero limit in `java.lang.String.split`, on contrary, looks more like a special value modifying the method's semantics. And so do the negative values, that evidently don't make intuitive sense as a *limit* and are not quite clear without digging through the Javadoc.

Comment: It makes sense because in Kotlin it is easy to manipulate the result like removing trailing empty strings by `string.split(";".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }`

Comment: Hysterically, this Kotlin's `split` was modeled after `split` in Python, where it works "consistently with itself"

Comment: I'm still maximally astonished at how `"ab".split("")` with kotlin.String returns `["","a","b",""]`, java.lang.String returns `["","a","b"]` on JVM 7 and `["a","b"]` on [JVM 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27477312/4506528). I will probably never pass an empty string to `split` from now on...

Comment: oh, come on voddan, its consistent with most of other programming languages, java one is wrong