# Feature in java which is no longer available in java 8

Tags: java

What are the main features which are no longer available from java 8 onwards

Comment: Java is built to be backwards compatible

Comment: @shinjw While this is the goal, this rule was broken few times for instance `"abc".split("")` gives different results in Java 7 and Java 8 (more info at: [Why in Java 8 split sometimes removes empty strings at start of result array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22718744))

Comment: Is this your homework?  You seem to be treating Stack Overflow like a free programming service.  That's not what it's for.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Well...stackoverflow is a platform to help each other when in need of programming doubts....i dont think i need any advice regarding it

Comment: @GreeshmaVSNair "stackoverflow is a platform to help each other" close but not entirely correct. New people often are misunderstanding *goal* of this site. They think we are here to help *them* specifically. That is NOT the truth. This site was created to be repository of programming questions and answers which can help *many* people, not just asker. Helping asker is additional effect, but because of that misconception askers incorrectly think that they are *entitled* to get answers for *any* programming question just because it is about programming, regardless of its quality.

Comment: (BTW I am not saying that this question doesn't fit here)

Comment: @GreeshmaVSNair Yes, we help each other.  So, how exactly does it help you if someone does your homework for you?

Answer (score 10):

See here : [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html)  .

Among the **Incompatibilities between Java SE 8 and Java SE 7** :

> In previous releases, some implementations of
>   `Collection.removeAll(Collection)` and `retainAll(Collection)` would
>   silently ignore a `null` parameter if the collection itself was empty.
>   As of this release, collections will consistently throw a
>   `NullPointerException` if null is provided as a parameter.

So your program could simply contain :

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.removeAll(null);
```

It will work in Java 7 , not in Java 8 .

This is one example, if you get through the above link, you will find several other ways to have such an *incompatible* program.