# split string android studio

Tags: java, string, android-studio, split

I have code like this:

[image: here's my code]

ans40 must be 2 but in some phones like Samsung s7 shows 3, how can I fix this?

sry for my poor English.

Thanks

Comment: Problem may be related to fact that `split` behavior changed in Java 8. More info: [Why in Java 8 split sometimes removes empty strings at start of result array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22718744) (use something like `split("?!^")` to get same behavior). But aside from that (1) please don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post. (2) Don't call `split("")` many times on same data. Instead store resulting array and reuse it when needed like `String[] arr = str.split(""); //then you can use arr[0], arr[1]`.

Comment: (3) to access all characters in string you don't need to split it at all. Just call `yourString.charAt(index)` like `char ch0 = anskey.charAt(0);`.

Comment: thanks for helping me out, and sry about posting image instead of actual text.
appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the array returned by `String#split` instead of using lots of variables.

```
String[] ans=anskey.split("");
```

Instead of using `ans1`, you can then just use `ans[0]`.

However, if you want to split for characters, you can also do it like this so you get a `char[]`:

```
char[] ans=anskey.toCharArray();
```

This approach is way more robust as `split` uses a regex.

And if you nedd to get the values of all variables, you can just iterate over them:

```
for(int i=0;i<ans.length;i++){
    //Do something with ans[i]
}
```

or

```
for(String distinctAns:ans){
    //Do something with ans[i]
}
```

Comment: thanks man, u solved my problem.
i owe you one <3.