# Is it possible to take a string of one word and put each letter from that string into an element of an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, split

I'm just wondering if anyone could answer a question for me?
Would it be possible to take a string variable of 8 letters and then put each letter into a char array?
For example:

```
  String str;
  str = "ABCDEFGH";
```

Would you be able to take this string variable and split it into an array of 8 characters?

**Update:**
       char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

will do it

Exactly same question, answered here:
[Split string into array of character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings)

Comment: This question is just lazy.  Google it

Comment: thanks guys but i've got the answer now

Comment: The question you've linked to is asking for an array of Strings. Hence the weird answer.

Comment: You can't edit an old question to become an entirely different question :p

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
String str = "ABCDEFGH"; 
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

Read the documentation for the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class.

Comment: okay thanks, didn't think it would be this simple

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you can use `toCharArray()` method.

```
String str = "ABCDEFGH";
char[] array=str.toCharArray();
```

Please make sure that you read [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 1):

You already have a method in String class to do so.

```
String str = "ABCDEFGH";
char[] array=str.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Fourth answer saying the exact same thing. Not even remotely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] arr=new char[8];
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
arr[i]=str.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Instead of a hard-coded `8`, you should use `str.length()` for the array declaration. Also mention that using the `toCharArray()` method of `String` is preferable.