# How do I read a Specific Line(string)(position) from a TextFile?

Tags: java, eclipse

TextFile

[Line 1]    `a=5`

[Line 2]    `b=2`

[Line 3]    `c=3`

[Line 4]    `a+b*c`

I want to read and output only the Line 4. How?

And also, I want to read and pass those a=5, b=2, c=3 into an Integer values(variables)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        File file = new File("D:\\TextFile.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }
        fileReader.close();

        String input = stringBuffer.toString();
        String output;
        InToPost theTrans = new InToPost(input);
        output = theTrans.doTrans(); 
        System.out.println("Postfix is: " + output + '\n');

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to read the entire file. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: You mean you want to do calculations then read result at line 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very trivial way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
throws IOException {
try {               File file = new File("D:\\TextFile.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            int lineNumber=0;
            Map<String,Integer> valueMap=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null&& ++lineNumber<4) {

             String[] sArr=line.split("=");
             //Here you have the number, do whatever you want with it.
             Integer iNumber=Integer.parseInt(sArr[1]);

             valueMap.put(sArr[0],iNumber);


            }


        String expression = bufferedReader.readLine();//Read 4th line, expression, delimited by space
        String[] sArr=input.split(" ");
        int operand1=valueMap.get(sArr[0]);
        int operand2=valueMap.get(sArr[2]);
        int operand3=valueMap.get(sArr[3]);

        char operator1=sArr[1].charAt(0);
        char operator2=sArr[1].charAt(0);
  // Now Calculate and output.
  fileReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: //Here you have the number, do whatever you want with it.
Integer iNumber=Integer.parseInt(sArr[1]);

I want to calculate those values using the given expression on line[4]

Comment: This really helps a lot bro. But if you dont mind, would you please give me the whole code? Im so tired with this sht ~.~

Comment: @user2758669 I guess you asking for too much spoon feeding :)

Comment: Yea, but I hope you understand. Im just a student who needs a lot of more knowledge. Without the help of someone, I wont be able to do this project. Actually this was my first time working with this kind of programming. :(

Comment: If you are a student, it is better that you should learn it by taking hint/helps here. Believe me, it is worth doing that from your future perspective. Just asking for a complete solution is not a right direction. Anyway, you have already told it a *sht* , and who would like to try for a *sht*

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out apache commons library:

```
String expression = FileUtils.readLines("D:\\TextFile.txt").get(3);
```

Not very performant, but the API looks elegant.

Comment: Use the apache commons library (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is like language processing, and purely parsing data and processing the same.
I would not provide you the code, but would like to provide an algorithm and love to see you implement that.

1. Read each line from line 1-3 in a loop.
2. Find the start index position of the '=' (Hint: [Use Java indexOf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm)).
3. Read from startIndex to end of string (Hint: [Use Java subString](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm)).
4. Parse the value using Java `Integer.parseInt()` (for integer vale) and `Double.parseDouble()` (for double value) and store in a local variables. (Hint: [See here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm))
5. Finally read the expression line string.
6. Split the expression string into individual character ([See an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings)).
7. Iterate through the character array and figure out each character and calculate the value through the expression.

I hope this should work for you.