# string.split("(?!^)") explanation

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to split the characters of the String to a String array. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings).

The solution is perfect, however I don't get how `.split("(?!^)")` worked. I'm familiar with the basics of `split()` method. Can someone provide an explanation?

Comment: Take a look at the Javadoc from the Pattern Class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Welcome to regular expression world

Comment: The split method takes the ´String´ representation of a regular expression as argument. More information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Take a look at lookaheads especially in your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(?!^)` is a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) consisting of a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `^` is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) used to signify the start of the string. `(?!^)` matches all 0-length strings that are not followed by `^`, the start of the string. In other words, it matches all 0-length strings *except* that at the start of the string.

For example, in the string `abc`, there will be 3 matches: one between `a` and `b`, one between `b` and `c`, and one after the `c`. Splitting on these matches produces the desired array (note that the 1-argument version of `split()` discards any trailing empty strings, which is why none are included in the resulting array).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, especially the reference links. My book never covered this stuff, so I guess I can't use it in class.

Comment: @user2280704 No problem, glad I could help. I personally would never use this approach since it's simply unclear and unnecessary. I would prefer a regular loop to create the array.