# String split method is leaving empty tokens at the beginning

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

```
String text="abc19xyz87nag";
```

I need to get only the numbers out of it, so I applied `"\\D+"` regex as below,

```
String text="abc19xyz87nag";
String[] tks=text.split("\\D+");
```

But I see a empty token in the beginning of the array
[image]

How ever I have found out two other solutions anyway as below

Using scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(text).useDelimiter("\\D+");
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
        }
```

Using Pattern and Matcher

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) { 
             System.out.println(m.group());
            }
```

So Why string split is leaving empty token at the beginning?
Do I need to change the regex to avoid it?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19503283/1679863

Comment: @RohitJain - Changes that I have to do to regex is not provided in that duplicate

Comment: It is. Go through it clearly, and look towards the end.

Answer (score 1):

It is a design decision to not discard empty strings at the beginning. The rationale is that split() is often used with data like

```
item1, item2, item3
```

(here the delimitter is ',') and you want to keep the non-null items at their positions.

Now, suppose you parse lines with 3 items like above, where the first and the last are optional. If split would discard both leading and trailing empty strings, and you get 2 elements back, you couldn't decide whther the input was:

```
, item2, item3
```

or

```
item1, item2
```

By only discarding empty strings at the end, you know that every non-empty string is at its correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex should be like

```
[^\d]
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "smt-ing we want to split");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer();
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: I think you didnot get my question...

Comment: String test = "1324asdasd9846";
   String[] tks=test.split("\\D+");
     for(int i = 0; i<tks.length;i++){
      System.out.print(tks[i]);
     }

Answer (score 0):

You can do some validation to remove that empty `String`.

```
    String text="abc19xyz87nag";
    String[] tks=text.split("\\D+");
    List<String> numList=new ArrayList<>();
    for(String i:tks){
       if(!"".equals(i)){
           numList.add(i);
       }
    }
```