# Java : split string to char array using regex

Tags: java, regex

I know there lots of way splitting a string to array.
but i wonder is there a regex that i can use it to split all string chars to a `String[]` array ?

For example : `"foo"`->`String[] { "f","o","o" }`

```
String input="foo";
String[] split=input.split( .... )
```

Comment: please look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
String []split = input.split("(?!^)");
```

but : `String []split = input.split("");` will get you `{"","f","o","o"}`

Comment: Actually this explanation is wrong. `(?!..)` is look-ahead, not look-behind, so it will split on every place which has no start of the string (^) **after** it (but it still works because both, `^` and checked places are zero-width).

Comment: @Pshemo: you alright it's mean "zero-width negative lookahead"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String input="foo";
        String[] split=input.split("");
        for(int x=0;x<split.length;x++){
            System.out.println("Data index::"+split[x]);
        }
    }
```

Output:-

```
Data index::f
Data index::o
Data index::o
```