# How to split a string without loosing any of its chars

Tags: java, split

I read this text from file "..1..3", want to split using split(), so that I'll get
 String[] = {".", ".", "1"...}; But for some reason i loose my 3 and gain a ""

Comment: And how do you do that?

Comment: And can you be a little more specific on your input/desired output please?

Comment: Using Java 8, `split("")` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the split() function. That is what you find out.
But you can do it this way:

```
"cat".split("(?!^)");
```

It will produce this:

```
array ["c", "a", "t"]
```

Source: [Split string into array of character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to do it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sample = "Split me if you can";
    String[] parts = Arrays.copyOfRange(sample.split(""), 1, sample.length() + 1);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[S, p, l, i, t,  , m, e,  , i, f,  , y, o, u,  , c, a, n]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string split by characters, why not using

```
char[] chars = mystring.toCharArray();
```

?

If you really need it as array of strings, add :

```
String[] strings = new String[chars.length];
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
    strings[i] = String.valueOf(chars[i]);
}
```

Comment: he already mentioned want to split using split()

Comment: But why? I don't see the point of bringing the regex machinery into such simple task.

Comment: +1, IMO, this is also a good alternative except that you get a char array instead of a String array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = "..1..3";
String[] trueResult = new String[s.length()];
System.arraycopy(s.split(""), 1, trueResult, 0, s.length());
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(trueResult));
```

Output:

> [., ., 1, ., ., 3]

Answer (score 0):

The `split()` method doesn't lose anything, check how you read your file into the `String` ( take care of char encoding , and to not forget the last `char`)

Yours

Comment: It throws out the delimiters.