# How to split a string into overlapping pairs of characters

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split a string into pairs of characters, but where the pairs overlap. For example, I have a string `Testing`, and I want the output:

```
[Te, es, st, ti, in, ng]
```

I tried some things with `String.split` but I am not getting the right output:

```
String s = "Testing";
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=\\G..)")));
```

That gives me:

```
[Te, st, in, g]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just do `substring()` in a loop.

Comment: Check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings

Comment: Thanks Flip Bulovic but I am getting my crieteria wiss solution below answer

Comment: @FilipBulovic [Since Java 8 we don't need `(?!^)` magic anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22718744/1393766).

Answer (score 5):

`String#split` method simply searches for places to split, it can't add anything new to result. In other words you can't split like

```
"abc"` -> ["ab", "bc"]
```

because `b` can appear in only one element in resulting array.

What you can do is use `Pattern`/`Matcher`, specifically `Matcher#find()` method and consume one character at a time, while "peeking" at next character without consuming it. The "peeking" part can be achieved with [look-around mechanism](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) because it is [zero-length](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) technique.

Demo:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".(?=(.))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group() + m.group(1));
}
```

Alternatively you can also use `String#substring(start, end)`

```
String data = "Testing";
for (int i=0; i<data.length()-1; i++){
    System.out.println(data.substring(i,i+2));
}
```

or using `String#charAt(index)`

```
String data = "Testing";
for (int i = 0; i < data.length() - 1;i++) {
    System.out.append(data.charAt(i)).println(data.charAt(i+1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pshemo for giving to me solution

Comment: @Sanket990 I was hoping more for giving you explanation rather than solution. If some part of my answer is not clear feel free to ask about it. Otherwise my answer may be kind of pointless for you.

Comment: I am running your logic code and my criteria wise this answer is full filled  i am already upvotted your answer .tnx

Comment: It is not that I am concern about upvotes. It is more like I would rather know if you are able to easily understand my answer. If there is something unclear feel free to ask.

Comment: ya ya i got your logic and i am easily understand thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As [@pshemo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31213381/256196) said, a split consumes input, so you can't get a given character from the input in two parts of the split.

However, here a one-line solution that gets the job done:

```
Arrays.stream(s.split("")).reduce((a, b) -> {System.out.println(a + b); return b;});
```

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

It would be quicker, theoretically, to just use a for-loop.

```java
List<String> split(String string) {
    List<String> split = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < string.length() - 1; index++)
        split.add(string.substring(index, index + 2));
    return split;
}
```

Output

```
[Te, es, st, ti, in, ng]
```