# How do I convert a String to array Integer?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to convert `String` to array then to an `Integer`,i made code working successfully in java ,but in **android studio** the array the i converted don't take the last value of array covered from string

```
   String y="abc";
    String[] array = y.split("");
    int[] x = new int[y.length()];
    for (int i=0;i<y.length();i++)

    {

       String letter=array[i];
        if( letter.equals("a")){x[i]=1;}
        if( letter.equals("b")){x[i]=2;}
        if( letter.equals("c")){x[i]=3;}

        sum =sum + x[i];
    }
```

sum variable always dont count the last value of conversation ,it should be 6 but i get 3

Comment: Where do you declare/initialize sum?

Comment: Also, maybe `if( letter.equals("c")){x[i]=3;}` fails somehow.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Yes i did all of this

Comment: Why are u using a **int array**?  why not replace `x[i]=1` with `sum += 1`? and ofcourse the same for 2 and 3. **so** you have: `if(letter.equals("a")){sum+=1;}`

Answer (score 0):

You should define "sum" outside your loop. To keep the value.

```
String y="abc";
String[] array = y.split("");
int[] x = new int[y.length()];
int sum = 0; 

for (int i=0;i<y.length();i++) {
    String letter=array[i];

    if( letter.equals("a")){x[i]=1;}
    if( letter.equals("b")){x[i]=2;}
    if( letter.equals("c")){x[i]=3;}

    sum += x[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i already did this after declaring method, always cannot read the last value i array ,but same code is working fine in eclipce

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
int sum = 0;
String str = "abc";
char letter = ' ';
char[] charArray= str.toCharArray();  //or use str.split (to a string array)

for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    letter = charArray[i];
    if(letter == 'a'){ sum += 1; }
    else if(letter == 'b'){ sum += 2; }
    else if(letter == 'c'){ sum += 3; }
}
```

This will split the string into an [charArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) and will than compare the character with the corresponded letter, and will perform the calculation based on the check.

**Check [this](https://ideone.com/Cp8ZBm) for the result**

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

> The below answer is based on Android Studio debugger output. Seems a
>   weird issue.

**array** will be **{"","a","b","c"}** with size **4** & hence for loop skips the last position since **y.length()=3**.  Try

```
int[] x = new int[array.length];
```

See the answer to this question [Split string into array of character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5235439/6127411) & [Why in Java 8 split sometimes removes empty strings at start of result array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22718744/2435238) &  for more reference

Comment: Thanks for answer , also same problem no change((

Comment: But you gave me the idea how to fix it, thank you very much

Comment: The array won't be {"","a","b","c"} fyi.. it'll be {"a","b","c"}. Check this if you want : https://ideone.com/SZCLOF

Comment: My answer is based on Android Studio. It seems different while running the code in Java & from Android Studio. Weird!!!

Comment: @layth you should accept this answer.. he is right.. Actually array length is `4`..!! see : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/333378..!!

Comment: It's better to use [toCharArray()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) in this case.

Comment: @AshishRanjan It can be length 4 & can't say it wont be. FYI

Comment: @sJy based on the output you were receiving , you're right.

Answer (score -1):

**Solved the Android Studio issue by :**

> string.split("(?!^)")

For complete reference see below code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String y="abc";
    int sum=0;
    String[] array = y.split("(?!^)");
    int[] x = new int[array.length];
    for (int i=0;i<y.length();i++)
    {
        String letter=array[i];
        if( letter.equals("a")){x[i]=1;}
        if( letter.equals("b")){x[i]=2;}
        if( letter.equals("c")){x[i]=3;}

        sum =sum + x[i];
    }
    System.out.println("value of sum : "+sum+"");
}
```

And this time definitely `sum` is having value `6`.

Comment: I told you it is working fine in java but in android studio app not working ,anyways i found solution it is woking fine now

Comment: It's in android studio you can see the user interface.!! By the way what was the problem ??

Comment: Layth - Note: Java is a programming Language, while Android Studio is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment).

Comment: public void start(View v) {
     int  sum =  0;int  sum1=  0;
        EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        TextView result  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
 
       String y=name.getText().toString();
        String[] array = y.split("");
        int[] x = new int[y.length];
        for (int i=0;i<y.length();i++)
        {
           String letter=array[i];
            if( letter.equals("a")){x[i]=1;}
            if( letter.equals("b")){x[i]=2;}
            if( letter.equals("c")){x[i]=3;} sum =sum +x[i];}result.setText(Integer.toString(sum));

Comment: check full code in andoid making app and you wil see the result

Comment: just put it aftre oncreate{}methode  ,then create edittext and textview in layout