# How to tokenize Chinese into individual characters in Java?

Tags: java, tokenize

I want to do basic Chinese tokenization, simply breaking the string into individual characters. How can I do that in Java?

String str = "这是一个测试"

I want it to be；

["这"，“是”，“一”，“个”，“测”，“试”]

Comment: `str.split("")`

Comment: If you are using Java 1.5+ then just simply `str.toCharArray()` will do, notice: this will give you a `char` array, if you need a `String` array then use `str.split("")` like the above comment, but you get an extra empty string as the first array element, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings/5235439#5235439.

`char` object since Java 1.5 can hold up to 16 bit of data.

Comment: @shmosel .split does not work here

Comment: @AnthonyAudette Works fine for me.

Comment: @shmosel my bad, I was misreading the question. I thought they wanted it to split into the individual components of each character.