# Java: how to split a string when you want a delimiter of nothing

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, delimiter

Say I have string A = "AAaabb";

How do I split this string when there are no spaces, so I can't use space as a delimiter.
Is there a like null delimiter, where it just splits all characters?

basically I want an array with each individual character
[A, A, a, a, b, b]

Comment: Do you mean like `toCharArray()`?

Comment: `s.split("");` there ya go

Comment: @sleepToken splitting by "" adds an empty char in the array. i.e if you call s.split("").length, you'll get 7  instead of 6.

Comment: @BluRe.CN While I'm sure `toCharArray()` is the preferred method,`s.split("");` does not behave this way for me .

Comment: wow thanks, s.split("") worked!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string into array of character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings)

Comment: @BluRe.CN it looks like `s.split("");` works in java 8+, so perhaps we are both correct

Comment: @HappyCoder Just be aware that `split("")` works this way only from Java 8 and later versions. Relevant question on that subject: [Why in Java 8 split sometimes removes empty strings at start of result array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22718744)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "AAaabb";
    String[] array = s.split("");

    for (String string : array) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

result:
A
A
a
a
b
b

Answer (score 1):

**Try this!**

Use **A.split("");** //A is your array

```
String A = "AAaabb";
String Array[] = A.split("");
System.out.println(Array[0]); // print A
```

Answer (score 1):

just do this :

```
    String input =  "AAaabb";
    char[] output;
    output = input.toCharArray();
```