# Separate_rows of dataframe on every character

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to `separate_rows`of a character column into as many rows as there are characters:

```
df
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  speaker A_aoi
  <chr>   <chr>
1 ID01.B  B*B*B
```

I know the `tidyverse`function `separate_rows`can be used for this purpose:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(A_aoi, sep = "")
```

Surprisingly (to me), however, the result includes a row - the first row - which it should not include:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  speaker A_aoi
  <chr>   <chr>
1 ID01.B  ""       # <--- should not be included
2 ID01.B  "B"  
3 ID01.B  "*"  
4 ID01.B  "B"  
5 ID01.B  "*"  
6 ID01.B  "B"
```

How can the `sep` pattern be re-formulated? I've tried to use `sep = "\\*|[A-Z]"`to no avail.

Reproducible data:

```
structure(list(speaker = "ID01.B", A_aoi = "B*B*B"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```r
df %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(A_aoi, sep = "(?!^)")
```

Answer found here: [Split string into array of character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings)