# how to split string containing binary into array

Tags: java

I am trying to do swa the bits but i have string which contains binary that is at first index[1] =1001 and at second index[2]=0010

I want TO swap there bits like

```
1001 and 0010 after bits swaps it becomes 1010 and 0001 and so on. 


for example
     A (array in string)
1.     1001
2.     0011
3.     1010
4.      0101
.
.
.    
now I want to swap the 1st two bits of 1 st string with 2nd string last 2 bits then 1st strings bit with 3rd so on
result :
     1011
     0001
     1000
     1011
```

I also applied this:
        `String array[] = gf.split("\\", -1);` but did not succeed

I just need to split the String into array. So just need help, thank you very much :)

Comment: Please post the code you have already.

Comment: see this post maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521921/splitting-words-into-letters-in-java

Comment: I just need to knoe how will I split the string. I applied this but compiler asking replace with length

Comment: again asking change to length. I don't know why this is so. my compiler is ecilipse.

Comment: do you want to swap chars at index 2 and 3 in a String?

Comment: yes it is also correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following for splitting your String:

```
String array[] = gf.split("(?!^)");
```

if you can work with Character[] you can simply do:

```
Character array[] = gf.toCharArray();
```

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/so4agw.jpg I have place the pic    cannot invoke toCharArray() on the arry type string.

Comment: OK so gf is a String[], thought it was a single String, describe its values... for instance what is the value of gf[0]?

Comment: 00001101 that the binery

Comment: Ok, so it is the String representation of a binary. And you have an array of String representation of some binaries.

Comment: It is a genetic crossover, do you need to crossover all the elements of gf and store them to array[];

Answer (score 0):

If your Strings represent the binary data as String of {0,1} then to swap each character on all of your Strings in the index array, one of the greedy solutions would be to run replaceAll for all your Strings 3 times (one for temp)

```
for (String s: index)
    s = s.replaceAll("1","2").replaceAll("0","1").replaceAll("2","1");
```

Comment: this will traverse the whole string?

Comment: give us an example of input vars and expected output

Comment: I have edited the code. I just need to split the string into array. I don't know why compiler not recognizing it :String array[] = gf.split("\\", -1);