# Java reading .txt file to array

Tags: java, arrays, file, text

I've been trying to workout this excersise all day, but not having any luck. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Here's the problem**

> The approach you are to implement is to store each integer in an array
>   of digits, with one digit per array element. We will be using arrays
>   of length 50, so we will be able to store integers up to 50 digits
>   long. We have to be careful in how we store these digits. Consider,
>   for example, storing the numbers 38423 and 27. If we store these at
>   the “front” of the array with the leading digit of each number in
>   index 0 of the array, then when we go to add these numbers together,
>   we’re likely to add them like this:
>
> 38423
>
> 27
>
> To simulate this right-shifting of values, we will store each value as
>   a sequence of exactly 50 digits, but we’ll allow the number to have
>   leading 0’s. For example, the problem above is converted into:
>
> 0000000000000000000038423
>
> 0000000000000000000000027
>
> Now the columns line up properly and we have plenty of space at the
>   front in case we have even longer numbers to add to these.
>
> The data for your program will be stored in a file called sum.txt.
>   Each line of the input file will have a different addition problem for
>   you to solve. Each line will have one or more integers to be added
>   together. Take a look at the input file at the end of this write-up
>   and the output you are supposed to produce. Notice that you produce a
>   line of output for each input line showing the addition problem you
>   are solving and its answer. Your output should also indicate at the
>   end how many lines of input were processed. You must exactly reproduce
>   this output.
>
> You should use the techniques described in chapter 6 to open a file,
>   to read it line by line, and to process the contents of each line. In
>   reading these numbers, you won’t be able to read them as ints or longs
>   because many of them are too large to be stored in an int or long. So
>   you’ll have to read them as String values using calls on the method
>   next(). Your first task, then, will be to convert a String of digits
>   into an array of 50 digits. As described above, you’ll want to shift
>   the number to the right and include leading 0’s in front. The String
>   method charAt and the method Character.getNumericValue will be helpful
>   for solving this part of the problem.
>
> You are to add up each line of numbers, which means that you’ll have
>   to write some code that allows you to add together two of these
>   numbers or to add one of them to another. This is something you
>   learned in Elementary School to add starting from the right, keeping
>   track of whether there is a digit to carry from one column to the
>   next. Your challenge here is to take a process that you are familiar
>   with and to write code that performs the corresponding task.
>
> Your program also must write out these numbers. In doing so, it should
>   not print any leading 0’s. Even though it is convenient to store the
>   number internally with leading 0’s, a person reading your output would
>   rather see these numbers without any leading 0’s.
>
> You can assume that the input file has numbers that have 50 or fewer
>   digits and that the answer is always 50 digits or fewer. Notice,
>   however, that you have to deal with the possibility that an individual
>   number might be 0 or the answer might be 0. There will be no negative
>   integers in the input file.
>
> You should solve this problem using arrays that are exactly 50 digits
>   long. Certain bugs can be solved by stretching the array to something
>   like 51 digits, but it shouldn’t be necessary to do that and you would
>   lose style points if your arrays require more than 50 digits.
>
> The choice of 50 for the number of digits is arbitrary (a magic
>   number), so you should introduce a class constant that you use
>   throughout that would make it easy to modify your code to operate with
>   a different number of digits.
>
> Consider the input file as an example of the kind of problems your
>   program must solve. We might use a more complex input file for actual
>   grading.
>
> The Java class libraries include classes called BigInteger and
>   BigDecimal that use a strategy similar to what we are asking you to
>   implement in this program. You are not allowed to solve this problem
>   using BigInteger or BigDecimal. You must solve it using arrays of
>   digits.
>
> Your program should be stored in a file called Sum.java.

**Input file sum.txt**

```
82384
204 435
22 31 12
999 483
28350 28345 39823 95689 234856 3482 55328 934803
7849323789 22398496 8940 32489 859320
729348690234239 542890432323 534322343298
3948692348692348693486235 5834938349234856234863423
999999999999999999999999 432432 58903 34
82934 49802390432 8554389 4789432789 0 48372934287
0
0 0 0
7482343 0 4879023 0 8943242
3333333333 4723 3333333333 6642 3333333333
```

**Output that should be produced**

```
82384 = 82384
204 + 435 = 639
22 + 31 + 12 = 65
999 + 483 = 1482
28350 + 28345 + 39823 + 95689 + 234856 + 3482 + 55328 + 934803 = 1420676
7849323789 + 22398496 + 8940 + 32489 + 859320 = 7872623034
729348690234239 + 542890432323 + 534322343298 = 730425903009860
3948692348692348693486235 + 5834938349234856234863423 = 9783630697927204928349658
999999999999999999999999 + 432432 + 58903 + 34 = 1000000000000000000491368
82934 + 49802390432 + 8554389 + 4789432789 + 0 + 48372934287 = 102973394831
0 = 0
0 + 0 + 0 = 0
7482343 + 0 + 4879023 + 0 + 8943242 = 21304608
3333333333 + 4723 + 3333333333 + 6642 + 3333333333 = 10000011364
```

Total lines = 14

**My code thus far**

```java
public class Sum {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File("sum.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String[] myInts = new String[50];
        int mySpot = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            myInts[mySpot] = scanner.next();
            mySpot++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < myInts.length; i++){    
        }
        System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(myInts[0]));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myInts));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to compact your question. People will downvote without reading any of it

Comment: all of it is important to the assignment though.

Comment: And does your program do what you expect it to? What do you think should happen when the program runs? What actually happens? Why do you think that is? Start with this analysis and then make your question more precise. That way its easier to get answers without people doing the work for you. I would suggest that you break down the problem to something very simple, like reading in the text file line by line. Solve that first.

Comment: The assignment is not important to us. Only to you. We would really like to help, but only if you are doing the necessary work.

Comment: Sure, it's important to the assignment, but is it important for what you're stuck on? Are you just expecting someone to spend an hour writing up a full report on how to develop the assignment and all of the design choices they made along the way? That's not what Stack Overflow is for. You need to be specific with what you're stuck on and have tried.

Comment: no, i don't expect that at all. just some tips to get me going in the right dirrection

Answer (score 1):

When all else fails read the instructions:

"The approach you are to implement is to store each integer in an array of digits, with one digit per array element. We will be using arrays of length 50, so we will be able to store integers up to 50 digits long."

Tells me that this line:

`String[] myInts = new String[50];`

Has some significant problems.

Tip 1: Don't call it myInts when it's an array of String objects.  Things are hard enough already.

Tip 2: Understand that `new String[50]` is not going to give you a string sized to 50 characters. It's going to give you space to store references to 50 string objects.

Tip 3: Understand that each line of your input can be solved separately so there is no need to remember anything from the lines you've solved before.

Tip 4: Read one line at a time into `String line;`

Tip 5: After reading a line solve the display problem in two parts: left side and right side of ='s.

Tip 6: Left side: display the line with spaces replaced with space + space. `line.replace(" "," + ");`

Tip 7: Right side: use `line.split(" ")` to split line on space, loop the split array of strings, each of these strings is what you'll be converting to int arrays.

Tip 8: "convert a String of digits into an array of 50 digits" <- Life will be easier if you write a method that does this.  Take a String.  Return an int[]. `private int[] makeIntArray(String num)`  Take care of the "right shifting/leading zero" problem here.

Tip 9: int and long aren't big enough to hold the bigger numbers so break the number String down to Strings of digits before converting to int[].

Tip 10: Read [Splitting words into letters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521921/splitting-words-into-letters-in-java)

Tip 11: Read [Split string into array of character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings)

Tip 12: Once you have single characters you can use `Integer.parseInt(singleCharString[index--])` if you broke it down to an array of strings or `Character.digit( chr[index--], 10);` if you broke it down to an array of characters.

Tip 13: "write some code that allows you to add together two of these numbers or to add one of them to another."  Read that carefully and it tells you that you really need to declare two vars.  `int[] sum = new sum[SIZE];` and `int[] next = new next[SIZE];` where size is `private final static int SIZE = 50;`

Tip 14: adding two of these int[] numbers to produce a new int[] would be another good time to make a method.  `int[] sum(int[] op1, int[] op2)`

Tip 15: Since all our int[]'s are right shifted already and always 50 long start a loop with i at 49 and count down.  `result[i-1] = (op1[i] + op2[i] + carry) % 10;` and `carry = (op1[i] + op2[i] + carry) / 10` will come in handy. Make sure to stop the loop at 1 or [i-1] will go index out of bounds on you.

Tip 16: Test, Test, and Test again.  Make small changes then test.  Small change, test.  Don't just type and pray.  Use the debugger if you like but personally I prefer to check values like this `System.out.println("line: " + line);//TODO remove debugging code`

Answer (score 0):

**Tip #1**: Initialize the array with 0.  That way, when you process the file, all you have to worry about is to replace the index locations with the digits obtained from your file.

**Tip #2**: You have to do some repeated division by 10 and modulus operation to extract the digits from the number (or binary shift if you prefer).  For example, to split the the digits from '27', you can do `27 % 10` (7) and `27 / 10` (2).  The key here is to store the result as `int`. After all, each digit is a whole number (not a floating point number).  For number of greater magnitude, you will need to discard the process digit position so that the number gets smaller.  You will now when you are done when the quotient of the division is equal to zero.  Therefore, you can say in pseudo-code:  DIVIDE number by 10 WHILE number > 0 (something like that)

**Tip #3**, you will have to iterate in reverse to store the digits in the array.  If the array has a length of 50, you will start with LENGTH-1 and count down to ZER0.

**Tip #4**: Use an array of `ints` not an array of `Strings` if the problem allows you to.  Use `Integer.parseInt(String s)` to convert the numeric String to a primitive `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question says to read each digit into a different array of standard size while you are reading all the words into a same a same array. and it will also be good to process this line by line

something like this

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int[][] myInts = new int[wordSize][];
    int mySpot = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
        while (scanner1.hasNext()) {
            String s = scanner1.next();

            int i;
            for ( i= 0; i < wordSize - s.length(); i++) {
                myInts[i][mySpot] = 0;
            }
             i--;
            for (int j=0;j < s.length(); i++,j++) {
                myInts[i][mySpot] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
            } 
            mySpot++;
        }

        // do the additions here and add this line to output file  
    }
```