# Given a string, return the first recurring letter of that string. If there are no recurring letters, return “None”

Tags: java

First recurring letter
Problem
Submissions
Leaderboard
Discussions
Given a string, return the first recurring letter of that string. If there are no recurring letters, return “None”.

Input Format

The input line contains a string
Constraints

The string length should be bigger than 2
The string should not contain whitespaces
Output Format

Return the recurring letter or “None”

---

Sample Input 0

```
life
```

Sample Output 0

```
None
```

Explanation 0

In the word life there is no recurring letter, so the output should be None

---

Sample Input 1

```
gjirafa
```

Sample Output 1

```
a
```

Explanation 1

The first recurring letter in the string gjirafa is a

---

Sample Input 2

```
statistics
```

Sample Output 2

```
t
```

Explanation 2

The first recurring letter in the string statistics is t

---

Sample Input 3

```
work
```

Sample Output 3

```
None
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: We don't do your homework. And surely when you don't even ask and juste paste **your** assignment

Answer (score 0):

For this code to work, you will need to split the word into its individual letters, which are stored into a String array `word[n]`, where n is the number of letters in the word. This can be done using a for loop and `split` function.

READ: [Splitting words into letters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521921/splitting-words-into-letters-in-java)

After that, you need to check each letter manually using two `for` loops.

```
for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
temp1=word[i];
for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
  {
    if(temp1.equals(word[j]))
    {
       System.out.println(word[i]);
       temp2="Yes";
    }
  }
}
if(temp2.equals("Yes")
{

}
else
{
System.out.println("None");
}
```

Next time, I would recommend that you provide at-least part of what you have tried so that we can help. Asking a question without providing code isn't good practice and should be avoided.